# How to plot stacked barplot based, when data is not periodical

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a numpy array `Xs` containing index values, and an other array `heights` containing hegihts. How can I plot a barchart, from these values elegantly, when some indexes are missing from `Xs` (I want an empty space there in the plot), some are present multiple times ( I want separate, stacked rectangles in that case)

[image]

My naive solution includes 2 for loops, getting the n-th elements, creating multiple Yaxis, and then plot them on each other using another for loop, with automatic stacking. Is there a more convinient numpy/matplotlib function to handle my data?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Xs=np.array([0,1,1,1,3,4,4,6,6,6,7,8,9])
heights = np.array([10,9,8,5,7,6,4,3,2,1,1,12,1])
values, counts = np.unique(Xs, return_counts=True)
print (values, counts, max(counts))

WholeY=[]
smallY=np.zeros(max(Xs)+1)  

for freq in range(1,max(counts)+1): 
    for val, cnt in zip(values, counts):
        if cnt >= freq:
            index = np.where(Xs==val)[0][freq-1]
            smallY[val] = heights[index]
    WholeY.append(smallY)
    smallY=np.zeros(max(Xs)+1) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
## stack them on each other automatically, create init bottom:
previousBars=np.zeros_like(smallY)
for smallY in WholeY:
    currentBars=ax.bar(np.arange(len(smallY)),smallY, bottom=previousBars)
    previousBars=smallY
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` might be convenient. Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Xs=np.array([0,1,1,1,3,4,4,6,6,6,7,8,9])
heights = np.array([10,9,8,5,7,6,4,3,2,1,1,12,1])

# Make an empty template with missing indexes included
g = {k:pd.Series() for k in range(max(Xs)+1)}
df = pd.DataFrame(heights, index=Xs)
# Get heights array for each index with groupby method and update corresponding entries in g
df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: g.update({x.name: x[0].reset_index(drop=True)}))
# Plot stacked bar graph from pandas DataFrame
# Fill in empty values with 0 so that there will be an empty space for missing indexes
pd.DataFrame(g).T.fillna(0).plot.bar(stacked=True, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My values are coming from a pandas dataframe, so using pandas is great. But this plot is part of a gui, with heavily customized labels, axes. How can I plot these bars to a specified axis? (using matplotlib's Object Oriented Interface)

Comment: Do you actually mean plotting to a specific "axes"? You can pass a pre-defined ax by [the `ax` kwarg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) in [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Comment: Yes exactly, I was looking for something like that, thanks